# Save ObservableCollection to textfile when closing MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm realtivley new to C# and WPF and have gotten the task to program an Alarm. Now I have the problem, that I have to save the set times to a textfile when closing the mainwindow.

The times are stored in an ObservableCollection of the type Reminder, a class i wrote myself and stores the time and name of the alarm as string.

```
public override string ToString()
    {            
        return ReminderName + " " + ReminderTime.ToString("HH:mm");
    }
```

My saving function looks like this:

```
...
public RelayCommand<object> SaveAllTimes { get; set; }
...
public MainWindowModel()
{
...
SaveAllTimes = new RelayCommand<object>(SaveReminders, CanSaveReminders);
...
}

private void SaveReminders(object sender)
    {

        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("time.txt");
            foreach (Reminder time in Reminders)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(time.ToString());
            }
    }
```

Now how can I bind the view to this function, that it's executed when the user closes it?

My view looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="Wecker1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Wecker1" 
    Height="350" 
    Width="310" >

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListBox Name="Liste" ItemsSource="{Binding Reminders}" Margin="10" Grid.Row="0">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding}" IsChecked="{Binding Active}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Command="{Binding SaveTime}" Content="Add Reminder" Margin="10" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button Margin="10" Content="Stop" Command="{Binding DeleteTime}" 
            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Liste,Path=SelectedItem}" />
    </Grid>     

</Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my approach using pure MVVM, not dependent to any other provider

xaml

```
<Window x:Class="CSharpWPF.ViewModel"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF"
        l:MyEventHandler.ClosingCommand="{Binding SaveAllTimes}">
</Window>
```

MyEventHandler class

```
namespace CSharpWPF
{
    public class MyEventHandler
    {
        public static ICommand GetClosingCommand(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (ICommand)obj.GetValue(ClosingCommandProperty);
        }

        public static void SetClosingCommand(DependencyObject obj, ICommand value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(ClosingCommandProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ClosingCommand.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ClosingCommandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ClosingCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MyEventHandler), new PropertyMetadata(OnClosingCommandChanged));

        private static void OnClosingCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window window = d as Window;
            window.Closing += (s, ee) => GetClosingCommand(d).Execute(ee);
        }
    }
}
```

so the whole idea is to route the events to binded commands via `Attached Properties`, you may create more handlers as you need

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code, you are creating your View and ViewModel. From my point of view (and this part surely is opinion-based) you should implement your On-Exit code there, because your saving of data is at the end of the process, not the end of the view. When your MainWindow was run, you can call a viewmodel method to save all it's relevant data.

If you do want to have it upon closing the view instead of ending the program, you can go two paths: the dark side, by writing a code-behind OnClose handler for the window. Don't tell anyone I said so. That's not WPF style. Or the correct path by implementing a Close-Behavior for your window. That's too broad for a single post, you should look up WPF, View and Behavior, you will find lots of tutorials for different behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use interactivity to bind `Closing` event to your `Command` like below

```
<Window xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SaveAllTimes }"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Window>
```